# Command Line: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in

Tags: php, command-line, sculpin

I am trying to download something using Sculpin, the static site generator.

When I type `sculpin install` in iterm terminal I get message

> Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in phar:///usr/local/bin/sculpin/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/String.php on line 18`

Comment: Which version are you using? It looks like the current name of the file is [StringConstraint.php](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/blob/master/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/StringConstraint.php)

Comment: History shows the file was [renamed on 19 March 2015](https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/commit/dc310ac54cd3323587ba33784a4489a1451b8faf)

Comment: I ran sculpin self-update and it says
"You are using the latest Sculpin version." version 2.0.x-dev

Answer (score 1):

Since Scalar Type Hint implementation,

> The names int, integer, float, string, bool and boolean are recognised
>   and allowed as type hints, and prohibited from use as
>   class/interface/trait names

This from php7. So, if you want use that package with php7, you need to update it to a newest version (*>= 1.6.1*). If you want instead keep that version, then you need to downgrade your php version to *5.x*.

Comment: I am on version 2.0 of Sculpin.

Comment: How do I downgrade php to version 5.6?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP 7? It's been fixed in JSON Schema v1.4. Try updating Sculpin's dependencies. It might fix the issue. You can find further explanations in the folowing link:

[Click here for the answer](https://github.com/sculpin/sculpin/issues/297)

Comment: Yes I am using PHP 7.

Comment: Have you visit the link above? I think you can find your answer there.

Comment: Thank you for the link Luis, it seems I am not the only person with this problem but the issue remains open and I have not been able to solve the problem from reading through that github issue page